# sql: how to make pivot table with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

Would you help me, please, to make pivot table from this (database in MS SQL Server 2016):

```
clients date_start  date_end    result
----------------------------------------
client1 01.09.2019  05.09.2019  red
client1 01.09.2019  05.09.2019  blue
client1 01.09.2019  05.09.2019  green
client2 01.09.2019  05.09.2019  red
client2 01.09.2019  05.09.2019  blue
client3 01.09.2019  05.09.2019  yellow
```

into this:

```
clients red blue    green   yellow
----------------------------------
client1 1   1       1   
client2 1           1   
client2                     1
```

Details: I have a table with clients' results. 
Each result is unique and it contains datestart and date_end.
I wanna select clients' results on specific date. If date is between date_start and date_end, it goes into the pivot table.

Initially, we don't know all the kinds of results (i.e. it can be orange tomorrow). It should be dynamic.

Comment: The solution for this is likely to be product-specific. Please tag your question with the specific database that you're using. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: This is typically better done in your application when you *display* the data.

Comment: Eric, thank you, the database is MSSQL.  a_horse_with_no_name, unfortunatelly, the clients' data is confidential, but the structure I displayed in the very beginning of the question is absolutelly the same.

Comment: Check this should help help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: Pankaj_Dwivedi, Eric Brandt thank you very much for the links. It completely solved my question.